# Find element(s) closest to average of array

Tags: ruby, arrays, algorithm, average

What would be a 'ruby' way to do the following; I'm still thinking in more imperative style programming and not really adapting to thinking in ruby. What I want to do is find the closest element in size to the average of an array, for example, consider the following array

```
[1,2,3]
```

The average is 2.0. The method I want to write returns the element closest to the average from above and below it, in this case 1 and 3.

Another example will illustrate this better:

```
[10,20,50,33,22] avg is 27.0 method would return 22 and 33.
```

Comment: What? The average of `[1,2,3]` is not `6`, it is `2`. The **sum** is `6`. And then how are `1` and `3` closest to either `6` or `2`? Please edit with accurate terminology and details. What if the array contains the average value exactly? Three values that are the average?

Comment: Also, in the future, please note that you should include in your question the code that you have tried so far to solve your problem. This site is intended to be for _helping_ people get the right answer, not _doing_ it for them. Despite the fact that this is what I just did. :)

Comment: Which values would you want returned for these two arrays, both of which have an average of 3: `[1,2,3,4,5]` and `[1,2,3,3,4,5]`?

Comment: +1 for thinking to do it in `ruby` way :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is not the most efficient, but it is (in my humble opinion) rather Ruby-esque.

```
class Array
  # Return the single element in the array closest to the average value
  def closest_to_average
    avg = inject(0.0,:+) / length
    min_by{ |v| (v-avg).abs }
  end
end

[1,2,3].closest_to_average
#=> 2 

[10,20,50,33,22].closest_to_average
#=> 22
```

If you really want the *n* closest items, then:

```
class Array
  # Return a number of elements in the array closest to the average value
  def closest_to_average(results=1)
    avg = inject(0.0,:+) / length
    sort_by{ |v| (v-avg).abs }[0,results]
  end
end

[10,20,50,33,22].closest_to_average     #=> [22] 
[10,20,50,33,22].closest_to_average(2)  #=> [22, 33] 
[10,20,50,33,22].closest_to_average(3)  #=> [22, 33, 20]
```

### How this Works

`avg = inject(0.0,:+) / length`
is shorthand for:
`avg = self.inject(0.0){ |sum,n| sum+n } / self.length`
I start off with a value of `0.0` instead of `0` to ensure that the sum will be a floating point number, so that dividing by the length does not give me an integer-rounded value.

`sort_by{ |v| (v-avg).abs }`
sorts the array based on the difference between the number and average (lowest to highest), and then:
`[0,results]`
selects the first *results* number of entries from that array.

Comment: `inject(:+)` Just as a shorter way to get the total of all values in an array

Comment: @SparkyRobinson But will return `nil` instead of `0.0` if the array is empty (causing an error when you go to divide). That edge case is the only reason that I used that form. +1 for pointing it out, though.

Comment: Note that @Sparky provided the reminder that it's not necessary to convert :+ to a proc for `inject`.  I thought that with the discussion of the initial value, that might have been missed.

Comment: @CarySwoveland FWIW it was not missed, but I did not realize that it worked for a two-argument invocation, i.e. `inject(0.0,:+)`; thanks for the impetus to check and discover the truth. It does bother me that this one Core method has this convenience, where so many others don't. However, it is slightly more readable and convenient, so I have edited the response to use it (even if it's just another one-off case of memorization magic in the Ruby syntax).

Comment: Perhaps slightly better to omit the initial value for `inject`, so the sum can be done with integer arithmetic if there are no floats, then divide by `length.to_f`.  Being able to pass a symbol to `inject` is a neat feature that is often overlooked.  One I like: `[{a: 1},{b: 2},{c: 3}].inject(:merge) => {:a=>1, :b=>2, :c=>3}`.

Answer (score 2):

I assume that what is desired is the largest element of the array that is smaller than the average and the smallest value of the array that is larger than the average.  Such values exist if and only if the array has at least two elements and they are not all the same.  Assuming that condition applies, we need only convert it from words to symbols:

```
avg = a.reduce(:+)/a.size.to_f
[ a.select { |e| e < avg }.max, a.select { |e| e > avg }.min ]
```

Another way, somewhat less efficient:

```
avg = a.reduce(:+)/a.size.to_f
b = (a + [avg]).uniq.sort
i = b.index(avg)
[ b[i-1], b[i+1] ]
```

Comment: Maybe `b=a+[avg]` so that you do not pollute the original array. Note also that two elements in the original are sufficient. +1 for guess at requirements and implementation.